# exporting database of html to excel

Tags: sql, excel

I have a database of products with their descriptions. I need to export the descriptions/product names for a translation service. The problem is the description is stored in the database with html formatting.

When I export the data to excel I have all the html syntax in the cells as well.

Is there any way I can remove the syntax? I'm thinking possibly while exporting not necessarily within excel.

I can copy all the cells data to a regular html file as well, and then open it in my browser and copy paste, but that doesnt keep the cell structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: How extensive is the HTML, is it a limited set of tags? Could you simply find/replace the tags?

Comment: What languages do you have available?  Do you have access to an HTML parser?  If just SQL, what DBMS are you using?  Can you use the VBA scripting in Excel?

Comment: There is a lot of styling in a lot of the HTML. I could use find and replace for a bunch but there would still be the css/styling which is different all over. I am using PHPmyadmin.

Comment: ehh... I was being lazy and didnt look that closely. Most of it could be taken out with find and replace. Still might be interesting to know in the future if there was a ton of styling etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save it as an html file, you should be able to use Excel's in-built functionality. In Excel 2007 and later, go to the data tab, and choose "From Web".

In the browser window that appears, point it at the html file C:\yourfile.html

It should open the file with all the formatting etc, and provided the data is in a table format, you should be able to click the yellow box to import it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (add a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library")

```
 Function HtmlToText(html As String) As String

    Static el As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Static div As Object

    If div Is Nothing Then
        Set el = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set div = el.createElement("div")
        el.appendChild div
        Debug.Print "created"
    End If


    div.innerHTML = html
    HtmlToText = div.innerText

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip out HTML in TSQL

http://cosier.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/tsql-strip-html-function/